# How to use TinyMCE 5 with Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, tinymce

There are no packages to support TinyMCE 5 for Django. The only available packages are version 3 or 4.
I tried this guide https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/
TinyMCE forms use native HTML and you have initialized it with javascript but Django forms work a different way. You have to make them in Views and I'm not that advanced to modify it. How should I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow instructions You provided and then just create django form and render as usual.
Make a selector from your instructions like this:

```
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
      selector: ':text'
    });
  </script>
```

This will initiate all textarea fields for your form.
If You don't want all textarea fields to be tinymce then add class in form init like that:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'tinymce'
```

Then change selector in tinymce.init to ".tinymce"

ALTERNATIVELY: You can install django-tinymce from https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce
then download tinymce 5 from tinmce site, put it in your static files and configure django plugin for new version in your project settings like this:

```
TINYMCE_JS_URL = STATIC_URL + 'tinymce/tinymce.min.js'
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': "silver",
}
```

I just tested this.

Comment: I tried the alternative but it's not able to read the `tinymce.min.js` file. Can you see what's wrong? https://github.com/saadat99/template_test

Comment: You have to go back to basics. I'm assuming you use dev django server so you have to serve static files. `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static'))` add this to your urls.py. Tinymce directory put just in static folder - not static/tinymce/js/tinymce/ but static/tinymce/

Comment: Still doesn't work. What am I missing? https://github.com/saadat99/template_test/commit/4dc814ce7a1add40b36a49d37bf2ac755ec8a7f0
Can you do i pull request or upload the working version?

Comment: One more thing. Add:
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]`
to your settings.py to tell django where static folders are.

Answer (score -2):

You can install TinyMCE V5 with Django admin forms (Python 3.6 needed) by following this [documentation](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configuration).

All you have to do is to take below steps:

1. Install tinymce module into site-packages.

   ```
   pip install django-tinymce
   ```
2. Add tinymce to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py for your project:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       ...
       'tinymce',
       ...
   )
   ```
3. Add tinymce.urls to your root urls.py for your project:

   ```
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       ...
       (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
       ...
   )
   ```
4. In admin.py replace the widget with tinymce.

   ```
   from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

   class ModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
       content = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
       class Meta:
           model = Model
           fields = '__all__'
   ```
5. In your settings.py, describe what plugins you want to use.

   ```
   TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
       'plugins': "table,spellchecker,paste,searchreplace,image,imagetools,media,codesample,link,code",
       'theme': "silver",
       'cleanup_on_startup': True,
       'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
   }

   TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True
   TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
   ```